# Can I create multiple splash screen on Xcode for both Landscape and Portrait orientation?

Tags: ios, xcode, splash-screen

I would like to create an app that support splashscreen for both Portrait and Landscape orientation and each views are completely different (multiple images in different position). Is it possible to do that? How?

If is not possible can i forced splashscreen to be always vertical (portrait mode)?

Comment: does your app support only  Portrait  or Landscape ?

Comment: If your app supports both, u need to set constraints correctly using autolayout . Else you have an option to design the seperate vc as splash screen and do your stuffs there. Did you tried any ?

Comment: I want to create 2 different vc but how do i start different splashscreen vc based on orientation?

Comment: My app support both!

Comment: PS: I want to load image1 if portrait and image2 if landscape or somethings like that!

Comment: What is a splash screen? Do you mean a launch screen? If so, that's a mistake; a launch screen is _not_ a splash screen.

Comment: NO i want a "splash screen" instead launch screen in ios! If is possible obviously

Comment: Then just put up a view, as desired, depending on the orientation of the device. What's the hard part?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "splash screen" in iOS. If you are referring to launch screen, this is merely a minimal screen that covers the time it takes the app to launch. It should *not* be used as a splash screen and no attempt should be made to display the app's full interface. (Besides, if the launch screen stays in place long enough for the user to study it, your app is taking too long to launch and you will be summarily killed when launching independently on a real device.)

You *must* use a launch storyboard (it will soon be absolutely required, and any other form of launch screen will soon be forbidden) and you should place on it just enough material to suggest the look of your app, such as a correct background color. Use autolayout to position this material correctly in both orientations.

Comment: Thank you for exhaustive answer, one more thing.. there is no way to remove completely "launch screen"? Because is too ugly se an app with 2 loading screen (LaunchScreen + My custom Splash screen)

Comment: @AndreaVaghetti You _must_ use a launch storyboard; otherwise, Apple will reject your app. The launch storyboard is needed because, as I said, something needs to be shown while the app is launching (otherwise the user will think the device has frozen). Even a large plain rectangle of the correct color will do (more usually, a large plain rectangle along with a navigation bar, if your starting interface has one).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use different images for different devices or orientation on splash screen you can create new launch image set in assets file (*.xcassets).
See screenshot for details[image]

Comment: Launch images will soon be forbidden so there is no point recommending their use.